# Has anyone used SciPy with IronPython?

Tags: python, scipy, ironpython, python.net

I've been able to use the standard Python modules from IronPython, but I haven't gotten SciPy to work yet.  Has anyone been able to use SciPy from IronPython?  What did you have to do to make it work?

Update: See [Numerical computing in IronPython with Ironclad](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2009/03/19/ironclad-ironpytho/)

Update: Microsoft is [partnering with Enthought](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2010/07/01/scipy-and-numpy-for-net/) to make SciPy for .NET.

Comment: If you need to mix .NET libraries with CPython C extensions, then Python.NET is the way to go.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Some of my workmates are working on [Ironclad](http://code.google.com/p/ironclad/), a project that will make extension modules for CPython work in IronPython. It's still in development, but parts of numpy, scipy and some other modules already work. You should try it out to see whether the parts of scipy you need are supported.

It's an open-source project, so if you're interested you could even help. In any case, some feedback about what you're trying to do and what parts we should look at next is helpful too.

Answer (score 8):

Anything with components written in C (for example NumPy, which is a component of SciPy) will not work on IronPython as the external language interface works differently.  Any C language component will probably not work unless it has been explicitly ported to work with IronPython.

You might have to dig into the individual modules and check to see which ones work or are pure python and find out which if any of the C-based ones have been ported yet.